# Trying to populate a table using repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to populate a table using a database. I've been trying to follow numerous examples but to no avail. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental as this should be this hard... Thanks.

```
    <table>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="data" runat="server" Text='<%= string.Format("{0}", My_Variable) %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
```

C#

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_connectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customer", Conn);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        rpt.DataSource = table;
        rpt.DataBind();
    }

    private void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (e.Item.ItemType == 
        Label l = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("data");
        l.Text = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell what IS happening?  Any exceptions thrown?  Any data at all present in your `DataTable`?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need the rpt_ItemDataBound for most simple variables.  In your .aspx file, try the `Eval()` function instead:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="data" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MyColumnName") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

`Eval()` only works in the context of templated, databound controls. It takes the data source you specfied, finds the item currently being rendered by the repeater, and lets you access member properties on that item.

You only need to use the `ItemDataBound` event when you need to render extra stuff that isn't in the data source, but requires need code logic to figure out how to render.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're most of the way there.  `e.Item.DataItem` is a DataRow (Since you bound a DataTable, which is just a bunch of `DataRow`s.  You'll want to cast that to a DataRow so that you can get stuff out of it.  Next, you'll want to get at some column, i.e.

```
l.Text =((DataRow)e.Item.DataItem)["someColumn"];
```

The other option would be to just do the whole thing in markup, which would be easiest if you're just taking a value from the dataTable and putting it in a label's text, but you may need to use the databound event if it's harder.

```
<asp:Label ID="data" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MyColumnName")' />
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this dynamically? (Not explicitly stating the column name?)

Comment: sure, but not in markup.  If you fix up the databound method as I mentioned in the first half you can pull whatever you want out of the dataItem.  I use a hard coded string for column name, but you can generate the column name however you wish, and it doesn't need to be the same for each item.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a simple BoundField as shown below...instead of a Label... (unless you need a label for any particular reason)...

```
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Your Column Name" 
            DataField="YourDataTableColumnName"/>
```

You can also do formatting using the "DataFormatString" attribute of a BoundField.

Hope this helps...

Comment: It sounds like he needs the custom template in this example based on comments, but this is still good advice in general and something he should know how to use.  +1.